# Is it true that factor spaces are T4 if product space is T4?

Tags: general-topology, infinite-product, separation-axioms

I use the following definition of $T_4$-space: for any two disjoint closed sets $A$, $B$ there exist disjoint open sets $U$, $V$ containing $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Is it true that factor spaces are $T_4$ if product space is $T_4$?

This is obviously true for normal spaces ($T_1$ and $T_4$), but i can't find any proof for "$T_4$ only" case. If this is not true, I need a counterexample.

Comment: You mean: If $X_\alpha$ are nonempty topological spaces, then $\prod\limits_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ is $T_4$ if and only if each factor is $T_4$? Or only the one direction, if the product is $T_4$, then each factor is $T_4$?

Comment: Only one direction, if the product is $T_4$, then each factor is $T_4$. Converse is not true)

Comment: Right. It isn't (not even for normal spaces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to consider the case of a product of two factors, so let $X,Y$ be nonempty topological spaces, and suppose $X\times Y$ is a $T_4$ space.

Let $A,B \subset X$ be disjoint closed sets. Then $A\times Y$ and $B \times Y$ are disjoint closed sets in $X \times Y$, so there are disjoint open $U, V \subset X\times Y$ with $A\times Y \subset U$ and $B\times Y \subset V$. Choose an $y_0 \in Y$, and consider the injection $\iota \colon x \mapsto (x,y_0)$. Since $\iota$ is continuous, $\iota^{-1}(U)$ and $\iota^{-1}(V)$ are open. They are disjoint since $U \cap V = \varnothing$, and we have $A \subset \iota^{-1}(U)$, $B \subset \iota^{-1}(V)$. Thus $X$ is a $T_4$ space.

The same argument works for $Y$ of course.

Comment: @MattSamuel: The point is that every factor is a nice subspace of the product and separation properties are hereditary with respect to such nice subspaces.

Comment: @MattSamuel That the product is $T_4$ is the hypothesis. It suffices to consider a product of two factors, since $$\prod_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha \cong X_{\alpha_0} \times \Biggl(\prod_{\alpha \in A\setminus \{\alpha_0\}} X_\alpha\Biggr),$$ so we can view all the other factors as one.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks a lot))